# Image url can't load android Imageview the actually image is"PNG" format

Tags: java, android

[See the image url](https://barcode.passbeemedia.com/pdf417/7/6/?text=C274.jpg)

If i load URL browser it's showing correctly, download the image from the browser after using online png to jpg converter using convert it's showing otherwise it won't show anything.
 I'm using glide and Picasso also my code is

```
Glide.with(this).load(imgUrl)
                                .thumbnail(0.5f)
                                .crossFade()
                                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                                .into(qrCodeImageView);
```

I tried many ways i'm not sure how to handle this please give me the solution for this, this url contains barcode image if i download image it's blank

Comment: Do other images get loaded?

Comment: Yes, Other images are loaded, but I loaded this image only can't load @kabuto178